# LuaLaTeX: define a macro that stores data to an external file

Tags: macros, luatex

I would like to implement a macro that allows me to give two arguments   and  and see this two arguments be saves on an external file ‘data_file.lua’ in a table, something like data[key] = value.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add an example of how the macro should be called and what's the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This writes a file called `outfile.lua`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
function myluacmd(k,v)
    -- see comment section below for discussion of "w"
    local out,err = io.open("outfile.lua","w")
    if out then
        out:write(string.format("data[%q] = %q\n",k,v))
        out:close()
    else
        -- somehow this never prints anything...why?
        print("Error:",err)
    end
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\mycmd[2]{%
  \luadirect{myluacmd(\luastringN{#1},\luastringN{#2})}
}


\mycmd{first}{second}
\end{document}
```

Its contents is:

```
data["first"] = "second"
```

Comment: You probably want to have `return { ... }` around the table content to make it easily loadable from Lua.

Comment: @HenriMenke of course. But there a more things to do to get a good table serializer (no string escaping of array indexes etc.), so I rather not post such a solution... :-)

Comment: +1. Since you're loading the `luacode` package, you could employ its `\luastring` and `\luastringN` macros -- the latter performs no expansion -- for a slightly more compact appearance of the code: `myluacmd(\luastringN{#1}, \luaestringN{#2})`.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I didn't know about `\luastring`, Code edited.

Comment: Note that this stores only the last call to the command because of the `"w"` flag, you can use `"a"` (append) to handle multiple occurences of the command (in which case you might consider clearing the file at the start of the document to prevent duplicate entries during multiple compilations of the document).

Comment: @Marijn good point. I have added a comment in the source code.

Comment: This is great, thanks! How would you call and print a value back to the .tex? I've tried with `\begin{luacode} local out,err = io.open("outfile.lua","r"); tex.sprint(data["first"]); \end{luacode}` but I've haven't got the hoped result...

Comment: @LordNexprex To read this back in, it is easiest if you have a syntactically correct Lua file, then you can use `dofile("outfile.lua")` to fill the array. You should a) accept a correct answer (if any) and b) ask a new question here or on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

ConTeXt gives us a lot of nice tools for this and some of them are available in LuaLaTeX as well.  To serialize a Lua table to a file in a way that you can load it again in Lua using `dofile`, there is the function `table.tofile(filename,root,name,specification)`.  The parameters `name` and `specification` are optional, but you will want to set a `name`, otherwise the default name will be `t`.

In the following example we check whether a file `\jobname.lua` exists and if it does we load it using `dofile`.  Next we initialize the table `store` if it is not already initialized.  The commands `\setvalue` and `\getvalue` perform the expected operations on the underlying Lua table.  To write the file at the end of document, we call `table.tofile` in `\AtEndDocument`.

The present implementation serves as multipass data in Lua, similar to the standard LaTeX `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.lua}{%
  \directlua{dofile("\jobname.lua")}%
}

\directlua{store = store or {}}

\newcommand\setvalue[2]{%
  \directlua{
    store["\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"] =
      "\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
  }%
}

\newcommand\getvalue[1]{%
  \directlua{
    tex.sprint(store["\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"])
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \directlua{
    table.tofile("\jobname.lua", store, "store")
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\setvalue{test}{\section{abc}}

\getvalue{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to load luaotfload. lualibs are loaded in the kernel and your file compiles fine without it.